# What is the best Jabber server (software)?

Tags: xmpp

What is the best, mature and feature rich Jabber / XMPP server?

Requirements:
- opensource (not must but preferably)
- runs under linux

Comment: also see [Which is the best Jabber server regarding performance?](http://serverfault.com/q/300031/58568)

Comment: Love this question! It was exactly what I wanted, I came here for it and found it and the first answer was extremely helpful. "Closed" status is very frustrating.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've found Openfire to be quite slick and not too much hassle (it's a Java app). The Redhat package installs to /opt, which I don't think is great, whereas the Debian package is very clean and "sane", last time I checked it out.

http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp

Comment: +1 for Openfire, we use it for our enterprise. Extremely stable, but make notice: They stopped developing the client (Spark), the user community is now updating the client.

Comment: +1 also from my side. I have good experience using Openfire. Everything can be managed by a nice web interface.

Comment: I also vote for Openfire.  We use it for our chat services and make use of their "Fastpath" plugin which allows web-initiated chats, that can be authenticated.  Currently we are using it with about 1200 users, but we are about to scale it up to about 20,000 users (though concurrent rate will probably only be a couple hundred)

Comment: +1 for Openfire, started to test it, it's real simple to setup on Windows.

Answer (score 14):

[eJabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im/) is a Erlang XMPP server, its easy to install (packages exist for most major distros) and simple to admin once you get used to the config file format.

If I remember correctly, its used to run some of the larger, public jabber services out there.

If your looking for quick and simple, then as above I recommend OpenFire.

Comment: +1 for ejabberd if you're running it on a Linux machine.  Because Openfire requires Java, it's config is a little heavier on Linux than on Windows.  If you're running a Windows Server, though, I'd definitely recommend Openfire instead.

Comment: +1 for ejabberd. Have 2 x servers on different continents using a single user-set. Easy to install, configure, maintain.

Comment: +1 for ejabberd, as I'm very interested in it!