# Which is the best Jabber server regarding performance?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I'm currently using Openfire and got about 400 concurrent users every evening. My Problem is: 1gb of Memory and two Xeon cores with 1.8ghz each are not enough for it and I'm pretty sure more power would not really eliminate the problems as it's memory leaking.

My Use case is as follows:

- Only MUC
- Users chat via BOSH (using punjab atm.)
- Flood prevention is a must
- Message archiving/logging is a must
- Webinterface for administering would be good
- External authentication is a must

Now my question is:

- What is the best jabber server for this use case?

I want one which is actively developed, has a good documentation and a plus would be a webinterface for administering.

I'm currently evaluating ejabberd. But the documentation is really awful. Or is there any good documentation about it somewhere?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: performant is not a word

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One word: ejabberd. No web interface though and docs suck at large.

Comment: Can't begin to stress enough how awesome performance wise ejabberd is. (but yes, truly awful docs)

Comment: I switched to ejabberd now. I'm really happy with the performance :)

Comment: ejabberd has a decent web interface. See old pics of it here: http://www.ejabberd.im/screenshots-administration


We actually switched **from** ejabberd to Openfire for a few other reasons - including built-in support for LDAP-based roster groups - but we had the extra memory to spare for the JVM to be happy.

Comment: @JimHerrick I wouldn't call ejabberd's web interface decent ;)

Comment: No web interface, but you can manage it from your Jabber client with proper RPC support, AND the erlang debug shell allows you to do many interesting things.

Answer (score 1):

Tigase (www.tigase.org) is very good option.
http://www.tigase.org/content/tigase-10mb-ram

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll take a look, although I'm currently evaluating ejabberd. Is the documentation there good?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is kind of late, but this can help somebody who is looking.
In terms of performance and scalability ejabberd is the BEST. This is because it is powered by Erlang.

[ejabberd performance metrics](https://blog.process-one.net/ejabberd-massive-scalability-1node-2-million-concurrent-users/)

Disadvantage: Lack of documentation, resources available for Erlang is extremely rare if you want to customize.

Comment: https://docs.ejabberd.im/ has tons of documentation, not sure why you think something is lacking

Comment: I agree there is some documentation, I felt it is not extensive.

Comment: What exactly do you like to see there? Could you elaborate?

Comment: If we need to customize MUC. Wanted to add couple of of fields. Keep the participants permanently under the room even they leave the chat. Basically like to customize MUC.